# What is a complex number that can't be written in polar form?

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

What is the cartesian form of a complex number that can't be written in polar form? Why can't it be written in polar form?

Comment: $0$ can be written in polar form; it just can't be done so uniquely.

Comment: I had the idea about 0 as well, but couldn't think of an explanation for that.

Comment: there is no such number, but you could learn more about polar coordinates at http://brownsharpie.courtneygibbons.org/?p=7